# How to separate text in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to extract each list member's email addresses from the list and append the extracted email address to the list named email_addresses.
I am supposed to use loops, split() and list slicing.

In other words, I am trying to get a certain text (emails in this case) from an element in a list but I don't know how to separate a text by "|" in the list.

```
list_test = ["David Parker|Clinical Professor of Information|csev@west.edu",
            "Daniel Van Lent|Lecturer|dabemc@west.edu",
            "Chris Teplovs|Lecturer|cte12lovs@west.edu",
            "Brown White|Lecturer|brown21@west.edu",
            "Chris Baker|Research Assistant Professor|chrisb@west.edu"]

email_addresses = []
```

The outcome should look like below.

```
print(email_addresses)
-> dabemc@west.edu, cte12lovs@west.edu, brown21@west.edu, chrisb@west.edu
```

Comment: looks like a homework question

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?  SO is not a place that you throw your assignment for people to do it for you.  Try to write code and raise a question here for the specific problem you encountered.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing [more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Got it. Actually, I tried multiple times to solve it but got multiple errors. I just thought it would have better to show as simple as possible not mentioning a lot of errors that I was facing. I will be careful next time. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for to loop all item in the array and split to seperate with "|"

```
email_addresses = []
for item in list_test:
    email_addresses.push(item.split("|")[2])
print(email_addresses)
```

Example : 
In item "David Parker|Clinical Professor of Information|csev@west.edu"
- item.split("|")[0] is David Parker, 
- item.split("|")[1] is Clinical Professor of Information, 
- item.split("|")[2] is csev@west.edu

So you get item.split("|")[2] and add it to email_addresses array by push function
Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

email_addresses = [item.split("|")[2] for item in list_test]